# Passing mouse control to JComponent which is not drawn inside JFrame

Tags: java, swing, canvas, awt, jcomponent

I‘m currently trying to render and use JComponents and it’s ancestors in a Custom Java Canvas. Right now, I‘m trying to create a Menu which should be clickable and it displays just fine inside my canvas when drawn with `JComponent.draw(g)`. But the last piece I‘m trying to solve is that it should also react to the mouse-events the canvas generates (like hoovering over a JButton, clicking a JButton, etc etc). I only found listeners for events generated by the component…

So, is there any way I can tell a JComponent to not use its mouse events but instead pass through the events from somewhere else?

Comment: You’re basically describing “hot” or “collusion” detection. You’re going to have to take the MouseEvent (which contains the Point within the component context that the event occurred) and determine if any of your drawings was clicked on. This is where the shapes API is invaluable, as it has hit/collision detection built in

Comment: Note that by "collusion" @MadProgrammer meant "collision". They contain almost the same letters but form entirely different words. English is funny that way. 

Comment: Back in the day I created a solution for this: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/

Comment: I’m on my phone without my glasses, you’re lucky it makes any sense at all 